# Numerical Analysis of Elliptic PDEs

Tags: mathematical-physics, specific-reference, research-level, computational-physics, differential-equations

I am looking for an elementary reference regarding issues of stability in numerical analysis of non-linear elliptic PDEs, particularly using the finite difference method (but something more comprehensive, covering more sophisticated methods, is even better). Ideally, something aimed at a physicist or applied math audience would be easiest for me to read, but that is not a strict requirement. To be clear, implementation of the method (using your favourite software or programming language) is not the issue, I am more interested in the mathematics involved in numerical stability.

Comment: This may be a good one for the new scicomp.se private beta. If you think so too, I can invite you.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but since this is already posted here, I'd leave it. Certainly the next question I have will go there.

Comment: No problem. It just went into open beta, so if you want to ask a question in the future then there's no need for invites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two collegues of mine wrote a monograph

[Faragó, Karátson: Numerical solution of nonlinear elliptic problems](http://books.google.hu/books?id=Gi26FA6ErWcC&lpg=PA27&ots=ncRfU7jhbr&dq=farag%C3%B3%20kar%C3%A1tson&hl=de&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q&f=false)

where conditioning and preconditioning are an issue. This may be some help though...

If you want it more elementary, then

[Larsson, Thomee](http://books.google.com/books?id=vZGCaLoEqwgC&lpg=PP1&dq=Larsson%20Thomee&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Larsson%20Thomee&f=false)

is the best.

Do you have a special equation in mind? That would help.

Answer (score 3):

Moshe, do you have access to coursework at the University of Idaho?  They have a course listing that has your question in the title of the course.

> [Math WS547 Numerical Analysis of Elliptic PDE's (3 cr) WSU Math 546](http://www.uiweb.uidaho.edu/schedule/catalog/2011/mathematics-courses.htm#o8006)

However, they don't seem to describe the course itself beyond that.

I did find this paper entitled:  [LECTURES on COMPUTATIONAL NUMERICAL ANALYSIS of PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS](http://www.engr.uky.edu/~acfd/me690-lctr-nts.pdf) (PDF) that may be more in line with what you are looking for (specifically chapter 2).

As for software, [MUDPACK](http://www.cisl.ucar.edu/css/software/mudpack/) is one that I managed to find.

Hope that helps.